# How to combine multiple source folders to single entry in Package view of Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Now I have a big Eclipse project, which contains multiple source folders and each one represents a single module. Currently in Eclipse I have to make a source folder view for each physical folder, it's very annoying everytime I'm trying to locate to one java file. Is there any way to combine them to one signle entry in the pacakge view?

[image: Eclispe Snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try converting each package to separate module.

Right-click on package -> configure -> create module

Reference: http://www.codenuclear.com/how-to-create-java-9-module-eclipse/

Comment: Hmm... This looks like not what I want... Based on the picture I attached, the expected result is like - One single line entry in Package Viwer, and if I expand it, all the packages will be shown under it.